# React throws custom hook type error related to onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I tried and created a new custom hook and came across an onClick type compile error like below

```
Failed to compile.

/Users/ryankim/personal/react/my-react-app/src/component/NCounterTwo.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/ryankim/personal/react/my-react-app/src/component/NCounterTwo.tsx(11,15):
Type 'number | (() => void)' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined'.  TS2322
```

And this is code

```
import React from "react";
import useCounter from "../hooks/NCounterHook";

const NCounterTwo = () => {
  const initialValue = 0;
  const [counter, handleIncrement, handleDecrement, reset] = useCounter(initialValue);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Counter= {counter}</div>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>Increment</button> // onClick shows squiggly line
      <button onClick={handleDecrement}>Decrement</button> // onClick shows squiggly line
      <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>               // onClick shows squiggly line 
    </div>
  );
};

export default NCounterTwo;
```

```
import { useState } from "react";

const useCounter = (initValue = 0) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    console.log('handleIncrement clicked');
    setCounter((prevCounter) => prevCounter + 1);
  };

  const handleDecrement = () => {
    console.log('handleDecrement clicked');
    setCounter((prevCounter) => prevCounter - 1);
  };

  const reset = () => setCounter(initValue);

  return [counter, handleIncrement, handleDecrement, reset];
};

export default useCounter;
```

I tried to change the onClick function to the arrow function like onClick = {() => handleIncrement}and the squiggly line disappeared but now even though I click the Increment or Decrement button it does not work at all.

I have no idea what's wrong with the code and how to fix it.

== Answer ==

Thanks Long for the answer. As Long said I needed to call a function with parenthesis. But after fixing it, it introduced another error

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'number | (() => void)' are callable.
    Type 'number' has no call signatures.
```

[image]

When state and functions are returned as an array restructuring in Custom hook, they should be cast with const.

[image]

Comment: Excellent fixes.

Answer (score 2):

Your try is nearly to happen.  Except, you did not call the function after yielding its name.

Please try again with: onClick = {() => handleIncrement()}

Comment: Thanks a bunch Long. Your answer was really helpful for me to fix the issue.